# How to send binary data through a HTTP request using a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to find out a way to reproduce a HTTP request that sends binary data in the payload as well as sets a `Content-Type: binary` header, like the following command with cURL:

```
echo -e '\x14\x00\x00\x00\x70\x69\x6e\x67\x00\x00' | curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: binary' \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6' \
-H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=m1q1hkaptxcqjuvruo5qugpf' \
--data-binary @- \
--url 'http://202.12.53.123' \
--trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

I've already tried using the REST Client (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and HTTPClient (https://github.com/nahi/httpclient), but unsuccessfully. Using the code below the server responded with HTTP 500. Has anyone done it before or is it not possible for the purpose to which the gems were designed?

Ruby code:

```
require 'rest-client'
request = RestClient::Request.new(
  :method => :post, 
  :url => 'http://202.12.53.123', 
  :payload => %w[14 00 00 00 70 69 6e 67 00 00], 
  :headers => {
    :content_type => :binary,
    :accept => '*/*',
    :accept_encoding => 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    :accept_language => 'en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6',
    :cookies => {'JSESSIONID' => 'm1q1hkaptxcqjuvruo5qugpf'}
  }
)
request.execute
```

---

**UPDATE** (w/ one possible solution)

I ended up running the request with the HTTParty (following the direction given by @DemonKingPiccolo) and it worked. Here's the code:

```
require 'httparty'
hex_data = "14 00 00 00 70 69 6e 67 00 00"
response = HTTParty.post(
  'http://202.12.53.123', 
  :headers => {
    'Content-Type' => 'binary',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6'
  },
  :cookies => {'JSESSIONID' => 'm1q1hkaptxcqjuvruo5qugpf'},
  :body => [hex_data.gsub(/\s+/,'')].pack('H*').force_encoding('ascii-8bit')
)
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

The body can also be written as suggested by @gumbo:

```
%w[14 00 00 00 70 69 6e 67 00 00].map { |h| h.to_i(16) }.map(&:chr).join
```

Comment: [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) might be able to do this.

Comment: @DemonKingPiccolo thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: You said you tried "unsuccessfully," but what does that mean?

Comment: `%w[14 00 00 00 70 69 6e 67 00 00]` does not do what you may think it does. It creates an array equivalent to `["14", "00", "00", "00", "70", "69", "6e", "67", "00", "00"]`. Maybe you’re rather looking for `%w[14 00 00 00 70 69 6e 67 00 00].map { |h| h.to_i(16) }.map(&:chr).join`

Comment: Incidentally, `binary` is not a valid value for the `Content-Type` header. `Content-Type` expects a value in MIME-type format, i.e. `type/subtype`. When POSTing binary data you usually want to use `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @Jordan, you're right. This value was grabbed by Charles (an OS X network sniffer), so I decided to follow it.

Comment: Instead of doing all of those operations on `hex_data` (`gsub`, `pack`, `map`, etc.), why not just use a string with escaped characters, as in my example? `"\x14\x00\x00\x00\x70\x69\x6e\x67\x00\x00"` will yield the exact same thing.

Comment: Alternatively, if there's a really compelling reason for you to have the bytes as hex strings, `%w[14 00 00 ...].map {|h| h.to_i(16) }.pack('c*')` saves you several operations over the `map.map.join` version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried this and it worked like a charm:

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI("http://example.com/")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.body = "\x14\x00\x00\x00\x70\x69\x6e\x67\x00\x00"
req.content_type = "application/octet-stream"

http.request(req)
# => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

I verified that the data POSTed correctly using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/).

[Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) is really rough around the edges and not much fun to use (for example, you have to format your Cookie headers manually). Its main benefit is that it's in the standard library. A gem like RestClient or HTTParty might be a better choice, and I'm pretty sure any of them will handle binary data at least as easily.

Comment: Thank you @jordan to present me the Net::HTTP. I edited the question description with other possible solutions I reached.

Comment: Following row: req = NET::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path) has a typo correctly it is: req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different reasoning here but hoping it helps.

My HTTP request only would accept `application/json` type and so the binary data needed to show up as a pdf file, sent through the body of the request.

Created a temporary file from the binary data and sent that through the request using HTTParty something like:

```
pdf_file = binary_data # can use gem like WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(content)

Tempfile.create(["file-name", ".pdf"], binmode: true) do |temp_file|
   temp_file.write(pdf_file)
   body = { "document" : File.open(temp_file) }
   HTTParty.post(url, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, body: body)
end
```

[About ruby's temp file](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html)